signature on amendment USPTO
in studying the I found this policy: An amendment must be signed by a person having authority to prosecute the application.
but no detailing where should I sign, anyone knows I just sign on the cover letter, or I also need sign on amended description?
I know that I need sign when submitting on-line, I don't think this is what it means.

Only one signature on the papers asking for the amendment to be accepted is required. On the cover letter as you mention.

The question specifically asks where it should be signed. Also you have a typo.

Thank you, I submitted it already
